# Why did the source of all living matter die when all Titans died, if it existed before Titan existed?

Tags: attack-on-titan

The source of all living matter existed before merging with Ymir and creating the Titans, then, Why did the source of all living matter die when all Titans died, if it existed before Titan existed?